# Is this fact true about triangles?

Tags: algorithm, math, geometry

I'm wondering if this fact is true since it relates to a programming problem I'm solving.

Given a positive integer `P`, there exists at most one set of positive integers `{A,B,C}` such that `A+B+C=P` and

- `A + B > C`
- `A + C > B`
- `B + C > A`

*Example:*

For `P=6` then set of positive integers that sum to `P` are

- `{1,1,4}`
- `{1,2,3}`
- `{2,2,2}`

but the only set such that any two elements added together is greater than the third element is `{2,2,2}`.

Is this true?

Comment: No. Take 2016 = 672 + 672 + 672 = 671 + 672 + 673 = 670 + 672 + 674. I couldn't fit "Trump" anywhere in that equation.

Answer (score 2):

No it isn't true. In general your relationships will hold for any A,B,C,P where A > P/4, B > P/4 and C > P/4. Because now, for example, A+B > P/2 > C. I believe that P=8 is the largest P for which there is only one solution (2,3,3). For P=9 there are two solutions (3,3,3) and (2,3,4).(correction, 10 is the largest P with only one solution).